# How to update gitlab-shell to 1.9.6 from 1.9.5

Tags: debian, gitlab

I'm setting up a Gitlab on a Debian Server 7.6

When executing this:

```
# bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production
```

Output:

```
Instance method "lock!" is already defined in ActiveRecord::Base, use generic helper instead or set StateMachine::Machine.ignore_method_conflicts = true.
 Warning 
  You are running as user root, we hope you know what you are doing.
  Things may work/fail for the wrong reasons.
  For correct results you should run this as user git.

Checking Environment ...

Git configured for git user? ... no
  Try fixing it:
  sudo -u git -H git config --global user.name  "GitLab"
  sudo -u git -H git config --global user.email "admin@gitlab.wiserobot"
  For more information see:
  doc/install/installation.md in section "GitLab"
  Please fix the error above and rerun the checks.

Checking Environment ... Finished

Checking GitLab Shell ...

GitLab Shell version >= 1.9.6 ? ... FAIL. Please update gitlab-shell to 1.9.6 from 1.9.5

Checking Sidekiq ...

Running? ... no
  Try fixing it:
  sudo -u git -H RAILS_ENV=production bin/background_jobs start
  For more information see:
  doc/install/installation.md in section "Install Init Script"
  see log/sidekiq.log for possible errors
  Please fix the error above and rerun the checks.

Checking Sidekiq ... Finished

Checking LDAP ...

LDAP is disabled in config/gitlab.yml

Checking LDAP ... Finished

Checking GitLab ...

Database config exists? ... yes
Database is SQLite ... no
All migrations up? ... yes
Database contains orphaned UsersGroups? ... no
GitLab config exists? ... yes
GitLab config outdated? ... no
Log directory writable? ... yes
Tmp directory writable? ... yes
Init script exists? ... yes
Init script up-to-date? ... yes
```

I'm stuck at this part:

GitLab Shell version >= 1.9.6 ? ... FAIL. Please update gitlab-shell to 1.9.6 from 1.9.5

Could anybody help how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding the gitlab-shell upgrade process, this is described in the [upgrader page](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/9e924c70f3bc1d173eb89149c369ca7e502e225b/doc/update/upgrader.md#5-upgrade-gitlab-shell-if-needed):

> If the `gitlab:check` task reports an outdated version of [`gitlab-shell`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-shell) (also [on GitHub](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-shell)) you should upgrade it.
>
> Upgrade it by running the commands below after replacing 1.9.6 with the correct version number:

```
cd /home/git/gitlab-shell
sudo -u git -H git fetch
sudo -u git -H git checkout v1.9.6
```

Comment: need to run `bundle install` afterward in the gitlab-shell directory